# Android Firebase - How to display a users information from firebase. User is displayed in an array and then want information shown in another activity

Tags: android, firebase

I have my users displayed in an array and when I click on the item in the array I want it to bring me to a new activity and display that certain item (users) information in a textView. I have the name working but the bio that is being displayed is the logged in users bio. Can anyone provide a solution?

[This is the array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmbsT.png)

[This is the second activity where the name and picture are displayed perfectly but I need to call the bio from realtime database thats where the issue is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuHCf.png)

See code:

1st Activity:

flingContainer.setOnItemClickListener(new SwipeFlingAdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override

```
    public void onItemClicked(int itemPosition, Object dataObject) {
                Toast.makeText(SwipeActivity.this, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                cards UserObject = (cards) dataObject;

                if(userType.equals("Dog Walker")){
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewDogProfile.class);
                i.putExtra("UserObject", UserObject);
                startActivity(i);}

                if(userType.equals("Dog Owner")){
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewWalkerProfile.class);
                    i.putExtra("UserObject", UserObject);
                    startActivity(i);}

2nd activity:
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_walker_profile);



        Intent i = getIntent();
        cards mUserObject = (cards)i.getSerializableExtra("UserObject");

        mName = findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        mBio = findViewById(R.id.tvBio);
        mImage = findViewById(R.id.imageZoom);
        mName.setText(mUserObject.getFname());

        if(!mUserObject.getProfileImageUrl().equals("default"))
            Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(mUserObject.getProfileImageUrl()).into(mImage);

    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    String userid = user.getUid();
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        reference.child(userid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0) {
                Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                if (map.get("bio") != null) {
                    bio = map.get("bio").toString();
                    mBio.setText(bio);

                }

            }
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Hi Alex, So at the moment I have a user being displayed in an array with their name and profile pic and I have that passing to a new activity. I then want to retrieve that users details from firebase but I am not sure how to call that users details from firebase as that user is not logged in. I am not sure how to set up the database reference for the array when there's multiple users in it, all who are not signed in. So, I want the specific users details who is being shown in the array at a current time passed to another activity.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot and indicate the exact data you want to get.